# can i use "index" as the name of the servlet name?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlet-3.0, ibm-rad

I am getting this error in RAD Web Application 3.0 Deployment Descriptor Editor:

> Servlet Mapping (index):
>
> Servlet Name:The value is not among the
>   possible selections

Then under my Markers:

> Web Problem:
>
> The servlet mapping "index" refers to a servlet that is
>   not defined
>
> web.xml
>
> /myweb/WebContent/WEB-INF
>
> Unknown   Web Problem

My web.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
    <servlet>
        <display-name>index</display-name>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/jsp/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

wonder what am i doing wrong..?

Comment: Is this error appearing on IDE or when running the web app?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a <servlet-class> specifying the servlet's class, inside your <servlet> declaration?

Comment: the jsp will be translated to a class i think

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to map your servlet to `/index`, but if you want it at the root address you need to map it at `/`

Comment: can you explain further as to how the xml should be :D
didn't get what you were saying..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Error I think is in the url pattern which you are using

use /index 
at welcome file list name

or directly specify
/jsp/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I just commented the declarations, saved and rebuild the project..
then it disappeared..
uncomment them back and seems ok again.. @.@
must have been one of those days..

Comment: That's why I asked you if it was a real web app error or just IDE. Glad to know the issue was resolved

Comment: Thanks for your concern Luiggi :)

Answer (score 0):

first, for the servlet-name of index must be allowed.

then, where dose your servlet-class locate? is it in the src directory?

please make sure.  Good luck!